# Django: set auth_login as homepage

Tags: django

I'm new to django. Problem: to see my homepage (that shows the default django login form)

i have to write the addess:

x.x.x.xxx:8001/login

I would like to access it directly through that:

x.x.x.xxx:8001

What i can see now if i digit x.x.x.xxx:8001, is the login page without the form.

I have:

in my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'license.views.index', name='auth_login'),
```

in my views.py

```
from django import template
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.views.decorators.vary import vary_on_cookie

@vary_on_cookie
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('login.html', {
    }, context_instance = template.RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are not passing a login form instance to your form.

Unless you want to perform some custom stuff in your view, your best bet is to use Django's built-in login view. You can set a custom template for it:

```
url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html'})
```

See this page for more info: [django.contrib.auth.views.login (v1.5) docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login)

Now, I see that you are using a decorator on your view, which implies that you do indeed want to perform custom stuff. In that case, I believe you'll want to use the **django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm**. Try doing something like this in your view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.vary import vary_on_cookie

@vary_on_cookie
def index(request):
    form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST or None)

    return render(request, 'login.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```